# Timer function is not executing

Tags: java, swing, loops, timer

I need to set a timer which would print after certain time in a loop. How can I achive it?

The following code stops and doesn't run.

I used timer function to keep it in a loop but it's not executing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("The document is available");
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Basically, the Event Dispatching Thread isn't executing, so the `Timer` can't be executed.  To use it, you will need some kind of GUI so the EDT is spun up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to temporary open a Frame, to start the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread). Something like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("The document is available");
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000 ,taskPerformer);
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();

    JFrame frm = new JFrame();
    frm.setVisible(true);
    frm.setVisible(false);
}
```

Another variant:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("The document is available");
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000 ,taskPerformer);
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(timer::start);
}
```

In this case you'll get an endless loop, that prints that the document is available.